# Change Data Duplication Exception MessageBox

Tags: c#

To prevent duplicate data input by user on grid, I changed a column of datatable in dataset to unique. And whenever the same data is input, an error show up.

> "Column 'ColName' is constrained to be unique. Value 'Value' is already present. Do you want to correct the value?"

There are two button in the error box, yes and no.
If I press yes then I was forced to edit the value to valid one.
If no then the row deleted.

I need to replace the box with a simple messagebox and delete the invalid row, but I don't know where to catch the exception since it's not came from my code.
I bind the grid to datatable.

Comment: WinForms, WPF or ....?

Comment: Its WinForms. I wonder where the exception came from.

Comment: Usually a DataGridView is binded to a DataSet (or a DataTable) and this datasource is updated through a call to DataAdapter.Update. Search for ".Update" in all of your code.